# Connector and python are installed but mysql installer is not recognizing them

Tags: mysql

I am installing mySql but there were some unfulfilled requirements. I have installed python 32 bit on my system but it is still failing requirement.I am stuck here for last two days and due to this failing requirement mysql workbench is not installing. I need some help.

[image]

[image]

Even i have installed connector but in installation their is error that connector requirement is failing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Connector/Python requires python to be in the system's PATH and installation fails if python cannot be located. On Unix and Unix-like systems, python is normally located in a directory included in the default PATH setting. On Windows, if you install Python, either enable **Add python.exe to Path during the installation** process, or **manually add the directory containing python.exe yourself**.

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html)

Comment: what if it is already added? i have selected "Add to path" during installation and python is also showing and this command is acceptable on my CMD ;

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue, I’m having the same problem. I added python to the PATH during installation and it is still not recognised by MySQL

Comment: Did you check the PATH, i9 am not sure, if it ever works, but you also don't need it use pip install mysqlclient and every works just fine

Comment: i have installed python 64 bit and now it is solved :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the python version that you have installed maybe you installed 64 bit instead of 34 bit